# Regex - match multiple lookahead conditions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to find a regex rule which finds newlines between bullet points and removes them. For instance:

> • Here is some text
>
> which flows to this separated by 2 newlines
>
> • This is a new bullet point separated by 2 newlines

Should become:

> • Here is some text which flows to this separated by 2 newlines
>
> • This is a new bullet point separated by 2 newlines

Here's what I've tried:

```
•(.+)\K\n+(?(?=[^•])(?=.+\n+•))
```

Where my thinking is:

1. Find a previous line which starts with •
2. Collect any character up until one or more newlines and discard. I'm now ready to match ahead and replace newlines based on some conditions.
3. Lookahead and check next character after newline is not a bullet.
4. If it is, check to make sure that after all characters followed by one or more newlines, there is another bullet.

I think my problem is not properly understanding how to chain together these conditions in the positive lookahead but struggling to find any clearcut answers / examples which deal with this kind of problem.

As ever, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: You would be better off to make this a two-part operation. 1) Blindly remove all newlines. 2) Find all bullet points and replace them with `\n•`

Comment: You can use `^•[^•]+` to get each individual bullet point and its data, loop the matches, and remove the newlines in each match. See https://regex101.com/r/sXooej/1

Comment: Do you mean like this taking care of only the 2 first 2 newlines? `^•.*\K(?:\r?\n(?!•))\r?\n` https://regex101.com/r/aV3Get/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - thanks for your input. I think this is a good way to a solution. This wasn't clear in the question but I need to keep \n within the document as a whole and only remove them if they're sandwiched between two '•'. Supposing there are 3 paragraphs of bullets at the start and 3 bulleted paragraphs at the end of the text file, this method would strip all newlines in between. The condition I need to enforce is that there should be a • on the previous line, and a • on the next line with no more than 2 lots of \n\n between 1st and 2nd bullet if that makes sense

Comment: How do you differentiate two bulleted lists separated by a single line of text versus a bullet point whose text went onto a new line? What if the final bullet point from a list has its text finish on a new line?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - It's a good point - In my case I'm working with a PDF so I convert it to an xml,  extract the bold text / text with a higher fontsize than the surrounding text which occupies one line and save these in a 'title' list which I can lookup and add the newlines back in around.

Comment: Does the XML file contain semantically regular data? If you don't have some sort of regular construct such as HTML's `<ul><li></li></ul>` then you are woefully out of luck in extracting your desired data with any level of consistency.

Comment: Yes, it's structured - I'm using Poppler utils' pdftoxml to convert from PDF to xml. From this I get together a list of 'titles' which sit between bulleted lists which I can lookup and add newlines back in around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match 2 newlines and then assert that what is on the right does not start with a bullet but does contain a bullet after that.

```
^•.*\K\r?\n\r?\n(?=(?!•).*\r?\n\r?\n•)
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `•.*` Match a bullet and any char 0+ times except a newline
- `\K\r?\n\r?\n` Forget what was matched and match 2 newlines
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?!•).*` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not `•`
  - `\r?\n\r?\n•` Match 2 newlines followed by `•`
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EiZ25W/1)

If `\R` is supported to match a unicode newline sequence, you could also use

```
^•.*\K\R{2}(?=(?!•).*\R{2}•)
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your input. The rules I need to enforce are that the newlines should only be removed if the following line is also a bullet. I've updated the regex101 example you kindly put together which probably helps put this into words more effectively.    https://regex101.com/r/O5cBcB/2

Comment: @lawson How do you know when the following lines do not belong to the bullets anymore?

Comment: If we have non-bulleted line which is immediately preceded by a bulleted line and immediately followed by a non-bulleted line, then the current line should not be absorbed into the bulleted line above - hope that makes sense!

Comment: @Thefourthbird You should check out the comment thread on OP's question. This could be impossible with regex.

Comment: @lawson Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/vfrsZZ/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vfrsZZ/3  - This is probably easier to work with as the ruleset is written into the lines

Comment: @lawson Would it be like this then? https://regex101.com/r/EiZ25W/1

Comment: @lawson I have updated the answer with the last pattern.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I'm after! Thanks very much for persevering